# How do you set keyboard shortcuts in GNOME 3 using gsettings or libgnomekbd?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

I want to write a GNOME Shell extension that sets some useful keyboard shortcuts when it loads, in particular those related to switching workspaces. I know how to set these easily from system settings, but I can't figure out how to do it programmatically.

There are some available options in `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys`, but none that do what I want.

Anyone know where/how GNOME saves navigation keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: After asking in the GNOME Shell IRC channel, it looks like most keybindings will be stored in `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`, but only starting around version 3.3.4.

Comment: If you are still around, please flag your question or post that as an answer.